# how come a view gets out of its linear layout parent borders without negative margins?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have this android layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/display_name_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
            ..."/>
        <ImageView
            ..."/>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/account_name_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_name"
            style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/account_name_chevron"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
      </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/close_and_recents"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:minWidth="@dimen/account_menu_header_horizontal_margin"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_close_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_close_button_size"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:padding="@dimen/account_menu_close_button_padding"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

but when i run it with big font size and screen size,

I see the image is getting out of the linear layout. And it's hidden behind the red circle image (a view in a sibling `FrameLayout`).

How can it be?

I didn't put negative margins.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in that LinearLayout first your `account_name` textview is taking space. So when you run with big font size, this textview takes the (almost) full width of the LinearLayout. Now the layout will render the next View (Image View), it will place it next to textView. Since the imageview has fixed dimension given, it will take its space but will not be visible as it exceeds the parent width.

If still not clear let me know.

**Update**
For your next question, you can change that `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/account_name_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/account_name_chevron"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/account_name_chevron"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

First we draw ImageView at the extreme right of the layout, then we draw textView from extreme left to starting of ImageView. For the Relative layout has properties like `android:layout_toLeftOf` and more.

**Update2**
Try this code as per your requirement. So basically what we are doing is; We fist draw `textView` and give it a `rightPadding` equals to `iconSize + iconLeftMargin`. So now the `textView` will always keep space for icon on its right. Now we `rightAlign` the icon with `textView`, so as the `textView` increase its space the icon will move with it. Once it reach the layout end the icon will still be fully visible.
`account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin` this the dimen equal to `iconSize + iconLeftMargin`

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/account_name_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/account_name_chevron"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/account_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how can i start with rendering the image and then truncate the text if needed?

Comment: @EladBenda You have to use RelativeLayout for that. I have updated the answer. Hope it help.

Comment: does the sibling order has to change? image before text?

Comment: Only if you are facing the same issue there. Else you can keep it that way.

Comment: but i want the image to be very close to the textView, and now the image is aligned to the parent right. but the gap between the text and image is too far away

Comment: @EladBenda Updated the answer with required changes, also I have explained it there. `RelativeLayout` is an awesome ViewGroup once you get a grip on it.